# Custom List with unusual label placement

Tags: lists, environments

I'd like to make a list environment (very similar to `enumerate`) such that the labels are positioned *above* their respective content, rather than to the left. For example:

`-    i 
First item 
     ii
Second item`

and so on. I've had a look at packages which allow you to customise lists but none of them seem to offer anything like this. I am open to the idea of making a new environment for this purpose from scratch, but I don't know how list environments are defined at the basic level.

Comment: Do you intend to nest this with other lists?  I ask because most of the work involves nested lists.  What you want can be implemented with a counter and \makebox.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I do not intend to nest them. I can see easily how the counter would work but I don't know how list environments control each `\item` text. (to be clear, it sounds like you know what I want - could you elaborate?)

Comment: The environment sets \leftskip (computed based on \leftmargin) and moves the label to the left using \llap (or equivalent).  \item also does  a \par and adds \itemsep vspace.  The text simply follows.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you - I'm not sure how to explain this, I understand the logic completely (I could write an algorithm for what I'm trying to do in another programming language), but I don't know how to actually write that in latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `label` and locally redefine `\item` to add a linebreak.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\newenvironment{bizarrelist}
 {\enumerate[
    align=left,
    leftmargin=0pt,
    labelwidth=0pt,
    label={\makebox[3em][r]{\roman*}},
    ref=\roman*,
    before=\changeitem,
 ]}
 {\endenumerate}
\newcommand{\changeitem}{\let\saveditem\item\def\item{\saveditem\mbox{}\\*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{bizarrelist}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{bizarrelist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you! (and I agree, it is a little bizarre)

Answer (score 1):

Is it this you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textendash\qquad \roman*, wide=0.5em, ref=\roman*, labelwidth=\linewidth]%
\item A first item
\item A second item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a centred label above the item body, you can use this code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={\makebox[\textwidth]{-- \roman* --}}, wide=0pt, ref=\roman*]%
\item A first item
\item A second item
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: I was intending to have the label centered in the page (I have modified egreg's example to make this happen). This is interesting - why does the line break between the label and the text?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood: I've added a simple solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

To complete what I started...

The code could have been simplified by setting `\parksip=0pt`, but since one might have a multi-paragraph `\item`, I went ahead and subtracted it out each time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\renewcommand{\themycounter}{\roman{mycounter}}

\newenvironment{mylist}{\setcounter{mycounter}{0}%
  \par\vskip-\parskip\smallskip% or whatever distance you want
  \vskip-\itemsep% remove gap for first \item
  \def\item{\par\vskip-\parskip\vskip\itemsep\noindent
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}\makebox[1cm][r]{\themycounter}\newline}}%
{\par\vskip-\parskip\smallskip}

\begin{document}
Text before.
\begin{mylist}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{mylist}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand! Thank you, I have already implemented egreg's solution but at least I now know what you were describing.